# Can a LMS adaptive filter be adapted for MISO?

Tags: equalization, lms, diversity

How would the LMS equalizer dimensions change for the MISO case?

LMS adaptive filters are typically described for equalizing a single input signal, $x(t)$. Can the LMS algorithm be modified in the MISO case to perform diversity combining when the transmitter has $N=1$ antennas, the receiver has $M>1$ antennas?

For the LMS algorithm, assume $n$ is the number of the current input sample and $p$ is the number of filter taps.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf x(n) &= \begin{bmatrix}x(n)& x(n-1)& \cdots & x(n-p+1)\end{bmatrix}^T \\
e(n) &= d(n) - \hat h(n)^Hx(n) \\
\hat h(n+1) &= \hat h(n) + \mu e^*(n)x(n)
\end{aligned}
$$
where dimensions are:

$\mathbf x(n) $ = $p\times 1$ vector
$\hat h(n)^Hx(n) $  = $[1 \times p]$ * $[p \times 1]$ = $1\times1$
$e(n)$ = scalar
$\hat h(n)$ = $p\times 1$ vector

Now define the $M$ received vectors, $r(n)$, corresponding to the collected samples from each receiver, $r(n) = [r_1(n), r_2(n),...,r_M(n)]$

There are two ways I can think of to incorporate the additional received vectors.

The first way is to change the dimensions of $x(n)$ such that it is $p\times M$

$x(n) = [r_1(n), r_2(n),...,r_M(n)]^T$

This would result in the dimensions changing as follows:

$\mathbf x(n) $ = $p\times M$ matrix
$\hat h(n)^Hx(n) $  = $[M \times p]$ * $[p \times M]$ = $M \times M$  <-- should this be dot product or summed?
$e(n)$ = scalar
$\hat h(n)$ = $p\times M$ matrix

The second way is how one of the answers proposed, is to concatenate individual inputs into $x(n)$. This would result in a dimension of $Mp$.

$x(n) = [r_1(n) r_2(n),...,r_m(n),...r_m(n-p+1]^T$

In practice we almost always use a fractionally spaced equalizer so the technique would require to scale for that use case. The first way could be extended for the fractionally spaced equalizer case, but the second way doesn't seem like it could. Are either of these right, or is there another way, or is it not possible ?

Note: more details on LMS [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter).

Comment: I think you have some naming inconsistencies.  Your title says MIMO, your text cites a receiver with multiple inputs and (presumably) one output, but you use "SIMO" to describe (presumably) your receiver.  Do you mean to say "MISO" throughout?  While that does suffer from its own ambiguity, I don't think I've ever seen cooking, Japanese or otherwise, discussed on this site.  So "MISO" is probably safe.

Comment: Yes I meant MISO. One antenna at transmitter and multiple at receiver.  I’ll correct it.

Comment: Sorry I left this bit out before: please _edit your question_ to reflect this.  Stackexechange like things tidy...

Comment: Fixed. Also, this link describes SIMO the way i had it in my original question: https://www.evercomtech.com/understanding-siso-simo-miso-mimo

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised I couldn't find a decent reference for this on the web.

Terminology gets difficult.  Let $s(n)$ (a scalar) be the transmitted information.  Let there be $M$ inputs.  Let $\mathbf r(n)$ be the received vector at each instant,
$$ \mathbf r(n) = \begin{bmatrix}
r_1(n) \\ r_2(n) \\ \vdots \\ r_M(n)
\end{bmatrix}, \tag 1$$
where each $r_m(n)$ is some linear combination of $\begin{matrix} s(n), & s(n-1), \cdots \end{matrix}$.

Then it *ought* to work if you let the $\mathbf x (n)$ above equal a concatenation of the individual inputs, i.e.
$$\mathbf x (n) = \begin{bmatrix}r_1(n) & r_2(n) & \cdots & r_m(n) & r_1(n - 1) & \cdots & r_m(n-p+1)\end{bmatrix}^T. \tag 2$$

Then just do the rest "naturally", using the equations you cite above.

The length would become $Mp$, where $M$ is the number of inputs and $p$ is the number of points you take into the past.

Comment: I don’t see how this would result in the combining of the received signal vectors to output one waveform that is a linear combination of the inputs.

Comment: Might be the typo in the definition for $\mathbf x(n)$ (now fixed).  In a "regular" LMS filter, $\mathbf x(n)$ is a bunch of elements, each of which is a linear combination of $s(n), s(n-1), \cdots s(n - ??)$.  In this filter, $\mathbf x(n)$ is a bunch of elements, each of which is a linear combination of $s(n), s(n-1), \cdots s(n - ??)$.  So -- they should be equivalent.

Comment: how would this extend to a fractionally spaced LMS equalizer? Seems like it would fall part since you only same once per baud.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question.

Comment: I can see why you want me to ask a separate question, but it's really an important detail to the original question, as LMS equalizers in communication systems are typically implemented at an oversampled rate. Might it be more appropriate if I edit this question to include that detail?

Comment: It probably fits in one question so yes -- go ahead.

Comment: Added some more detail to the question. Please take a look. I'm not great with Latex formatting so apologizes in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My communication knowledge is rusty. Bit you are using some kind of known training sequence in a single transmitter antenna, to identify the linear convolutive system from Tx antenna to each Rx antenna so you can combine them using eg matched filtering?

If so, I think that each system can be identified using LMS simultaneously but independently?

Comment: Yes, there would be a known sequence like a training sequence or pilots to perform synchronization

Comment: Then, as I said, I fail to see the problem. Identify the N paths from the 1 pilot using N LMS filters. Do whatever to combine the N Rx antennas with known convolutive distortion.